# How to calculate randomForest training AUC in R

Tags: r, random-forest, training-data, auc

I am sorry for posting this question again but I really need help on this now.
I am trying to calculate the AUC of training set of randomForest model in R and there are two ways to calculate this but give different results. The following is a reproductible example of my question. I really appreciate it if someone could help!!!

```
library(randomForest)
library(pROC)
library(ROCR)
# prep training to binary outcome
train <- iris[iris$Species %in% c('virginica', 'versicolor'),]
train$Species <- droplevels(train$Species)

# build model
rfmodel <- randomForest(Species~., data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=2)

#the first way to calculate training auc
rf_p_train <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob",newdata = train)[,2]
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species)
r_auc_train1 <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]] 
r_auc_train1    #0.9888


#the second way to calculate training auc
rf_p_train <- as.vector(rfmodel$votes[,2])
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species);
r_auc_train2 <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]]
r_auc_train2  #0.9175
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive the same results for both prediction functions you should exclude the newdata parameter from the first one (explained in the package documentation for the *predict* function),

```
rf_p_train <- predict(rfmodel, type="prob")[,2]
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species)
r_auc_train1 <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]] 
r_auc_train1
```

returns,

```
[1] 0.8655172
```

The second function returns the OOB votes as explained in the package documentation of the *randomForest* function,

```
rf_p_train <- as.vector(rfmodel$votes[,2])
rf_pr_train <- prediction(rf_p_train, train$Species);
r_auc_train2 <- performance(rf_pr_train, measure = "auc")@y.values[[1]]
r_auc_train2
```

returns (the same result),

```
[1] 0.8655172
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! I should have looked into the documents.

Comment: But is it possible that the AUC of test data is higher than that of the train data in randomForest? I have worked on other data and the AUC of test set is always higher than that of the train data. Could you help me with this ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @annadai, I think that the proper way would be to post a new question with your (sample) data.

Comment: The question is here. Thanks a lot for the help! https://stackoverflow.com/q/46812212/8737443